# How easy is lazy evaluation by converting a non-lazy collection to a stream?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-2.11

This might be a silly question, but I've been unsure of it for a while. Let's assume this iterates over our list three times:

```
def doSomething(list: List[Int]): List[Int] =
  list.map(...).flatMap(...).map(...)
```

If I instead do:

```
def doSomething(list: List[Int]): List[Int] =
  list.toStream.map(...).flatMap(...).map(...).toList
```

Am I guaranteed a single iteration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, converting to .toStream should do the iteration only once.
Though, the more standard way of doing this is using `.view` and then `.force` at the end

```
def doSomething(list: List[Int]): List[Int] =
  list.view.map(...).flatMap(...).map(...).force
```

Using `.view` on a collection returns a lazy version of it, and calling `.force` on the lazy view creates the collection.

Comment: Thanks. Googling your answer lead me to [this](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/stream-view-iterator.html), which is also very helpful. Looks like `view`/`force` is the way to go. That said, I would love something that explained in more detail how streams differed from views.